Errors were encountered while processing: shim-signed
I want to update the packages on my laptop which has ubuntu and I keep getting error about shim-signed package.
Here is the error
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/shim-signed/shim-signed_1.40.10+15.8-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i shim-signed_1.40.10+15.8-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up shim-signed (1.40.10+15.8-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing package shim-signed (--configure):
 installed shim-signed package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 shim-signed
>>> sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up shim-signed (1.40.10+15.8-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing package shim-signed (--configure):
 installed shim-signed package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 shim-signed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Even to update other packages I will run into this error again
>>>sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
nvidia-cuda-toolkit is already the newest version (10.1.243-3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up shim-signed (1.40.10+15.8-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing package shim-signed (--configure):
 installed shim-signed package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 shim-signed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I will appreciate if someone can suggest a way to fix this error.

I suggest checking your question & tagged release, as your paste shows shim-signed | 1.40.10+15.8-0ubuntu1                 | focal-updates   | amd64, arm64 which is 20.04 or focal and not shim-signed | 1.51.3+15.7-0ubuntu1                  | jammy-security  | amd64, arm64 which is the release you tagged. What are you running?
